# making a image slider using twitter bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

so here I'm trying to make an image slider using twitter bootstrap carousel, the problem is, the next, previous, and the caption is not exactly how it supposed to be, this the the screenshot:

[image]

notice the prev and next icon is on the top left and right, while it supposed to be in the center, by the way, here's the code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                    <!-- Carousel slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner" width="100%" height="100%">
                        <div class="active item">
                            <img alt="" src="http://www.trexglobal.com/property-management/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/real-estate-investment-property-canada.jpg"
                                style="width: 750px; height: 300px;" />
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h4>
                                    CAPTION</h4>
                                <p>
                                    Sample Caption</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img alt="" src="http://news.worldwidepropertydevelopments.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/feature.jpg"
                                style="width: 750px; height: 300px;" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img alt="" src="http://images.realestate.com/re/homepage/theme4/2.jpg" style="width: 750px;
                                height: 300px;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Carousel navigation -->
                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a> <a class="carousel-control right"
                        href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
                </div>
```

what did i do wrong here? any suggestion? thanks.

oh and by the way, i used bootstrap v3 if it's helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

Just make sure the position comes first (i.e.: `left` or `right`) before `carousel-control`

right answer:
`class="left carousel-control"`

not-so-right answer:
`class="carousel-control left"`

also i edited the navigation code into:

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-generic" data-slide="prev"><span
   class="icon-prev"></span></a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-generic"
     data-slide="next"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>
```

cheers!